# Site doesn’t put .php after link

Tags: php

Hello everyone I have a small problem. I am pretty new to this so please go easy on me. So my problem is that my site doesn’t put .php after the php files. For example: domain/index. This is what i have know. This is how it should be: domain/index.php. Hope y’all can help me!

Comment: I am not sure what u mean by this. Do you mean when you run it on localhost, it does not show the .PHP extension, or when you redirect to a certain file and the file did not show the .PHP extension

Comment: Yeah, i am hosting my site on a vps whenever I click on a redirect it redirects me to index not index.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the file name in your anchor tag(HTML) or header function (PHP) has the extension of `.php`

```
<a href="NextPage.php">Next Page</a>
```

or

```
header('Location: NextPage.php');
```